# Is this relation symmetric on $\mathbb{Z} \times ( \mathbb{Z} \backslash \{0\}) $

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, equivalence-relations

Define a relation  $R$ on  $\mathbb{Z} \times ( \mathbb{Z} \backslash \{0\})$ by $(a, b) R (x, y)$ iff $ay = bx$.

Checking whether $R$ is symmetric.

$(a,b)R(b,a) \implies a.a = b.b$ which is false for $a = 2$ and $b = 3$.

In the book : Analysis with an introduction to proof, 5th Ed by Steven Lay on Page 65, it is being asked prove that $R$ is an equivalence relation.

I think I have proven $R$ is not an equivalence relation.

Can you verify?

Comment: That isn't the correct definition of a symmetric relation. A relation is symmetric if $xRy$ implies $yRx$. You need to remember that $(a,b)$ is a single element here.

Comment: @ZachEffman is right, you need to show $(a,b)R(a,b)$ (reflexive.) But your definition of reflexive is incorrect.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I think that you're describing reflexive, not symmetric.

Comment: Yes, already fixed before your comment, @MichaelBurr :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check that the relation is symmetric:  The elements here are of the form $(a,b)\in\mathbb{Z}\times(\mathbb{Z}\setminus \{0\})$.  So, you need two elements: $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$.  Therefore, you must show that 
$$(a,b)R(c,d)\Rightarrow(c,d)R(a,b).$$
Assuming $(a,b)R(c,d)$ means that $ad=bc$.  This is, however, (after rearrangement) the same as the relation that you need for $(c,d)R(a,b)$, which is $cb=da$.